# Connection from outside refused to webserver on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I can ssh to my EC2 instance and start a web server on it:

```
$ ssh -i ~/AWSKeyPair1.pem ec2-user@54.210.10.190
Last login: Mon Jul 20 18:50:58 2015 from 72-21-196-64.amazon.com

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2015.03-release-notes/
$ echo 'Hello world' > index.html
$ sudo service iptables status
iptables: Firewall is not running.
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8888 ...
```

And curl it from the instance

```
$ curl 54.210.10.190:8888
Hello world
```

But `curl`s from my laptop fail

```
$ curl 54.210.10.190:8888
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 54.210.10.190 port 8888: Connection refused
```

Why might this be? My Security Groups are set to allow all traffic from anywhere (`0.0.0.0/0`), and my Route Table routes all traffic to the appropriate gateway.

([Previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/705296/ec2-instance-not-responding-to-ping/705322))

Comment: `$ sudo netstat -a -n | grep 8888` from another terminal while the web server is running.  What does it show?

Comment: Incidentally, this works from my mobile phone.  Possibly an issue with your laptop or the network your laptop is on?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have your AWS security groups are setup to allow access at 0.0.0.0/0 port 8888 using a custom TCP rule.

verify your local network firewall allows outbound connections to port 8888.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the python server running on the aws instance was only listening (and serving) to localhost or 127.0.0.1 / interface. Thus it will ignore connections from the outside. For me starting the python server on 0.0.0.0 worked. From the output you printed it looks like, it already does - but might be worth a shot or help others

Comment: dude you are a life saver i totally forgot to remove localhost! Thanks